# SDK setup for Flutter app won´t finish in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I made a Flutter app which i try to connect to Firebase (via console) to use a database. 
The app registration has been done and the google services file as well as the Firebase SDK are added to the Android section in my project.

The connection gets checked on step 4 but it won´t proceed.

My guess is that the Firebase SDK might not be synced yet. I didn´t find any "Sync now" button for my Gradle files in the Flutter project. I also added the Google Services.json file anew several times but it didn´t change anything.

Looking forward for your tips and answers.

Greetings.